# how do I create a compound index after the fact in neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Can I use the power tool console in the neo4j admin to create a compound index after the objects have been created?  I currently add a node than add it's "name" property to an "Apps" index.  Now I also want to create a "platform" and "storeId" compound index as well.  BTW, should I add that to the same Apps index or create a new index.

Comment: I'm pretty sure (>50% confidence) that you must create complex indexes via REST or through the API for embedded. (as opposed to using the admin console). Not posting as an answer because I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can create new indexes and also add existing nodes through the console.

Most sensibly by [executing a script fragment](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/shell-commands.html#_executing_groovy_python_scripts), see the [console online manual](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/shell-commands.html#_indexing) and issue `help index` the console.

So either use something like this:

```
index -q Apps "name:*" -c cd -a $i && index -i Apps storeId
```

Otherwise use eval to evaluate a javascript fragment:

```
eval                                                   
  index=db.index().forNodes("Apps")                   
  nodes=index.query("name:*")                            
  while ( nodes.hasNext() ) {                            
     node=nodes.next()                                   
     index.add(node,"storeId",node.getProperty("storeId"))
  }
```